# Rails includes with conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Is is possible in Rails > 3.2 to add conditions to the join statement generated by the `includes` method?

Let's say I have two models, Person and Note. Each person has many notes and each note belong to one person. Each note has an attribute `important`.

I want to find all the people preloading only the notes that are important. In SQL that will be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM people
LEFT JOIN notes ON notes.person_id = people.id AND notes.important = 't'
```

In Rails, the only similar way to do that is using `includes` (note: `joins` won't preload notes) like this:

```sql
Person.includes(:notes).where(:important, true)
```

However, that will generate the following SQL query which returns a different result set:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM people
LEFT JOIN notes ON notes.person_id = people.id
WHERE notes.important = 't'
```

Please, notice that the first resultset includes all the people and the second one only the people associated to important notes.

Also notice that :conditions are deprecated since 3.1.

Comment: Is there any difference in performance? notes.important = 't' in a join clause is not semantic, since it only takes in consideration one model.

Comment: Yes. It's a matter of performance. I need all the people, eager loading important notes if there are any.

Comment: [Rails Active Record Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) says "If, in the case of this includes query, there were no comments(notes, in this example) for any articles(Persons), all the articles(Persons) would still be loaded. By using joins (an INNER JOIN), the join conditions must match, otherwise no records will be returned.". This really doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 47):

According to this guide [Active Record Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

You can specify conditions on includes for eager loading like this

```
Person.includes(:notes).where("notes.important", true)
```

It recommends to use `joins` anyway.

A workaround for this would be to create another association like this

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :important_notes, :class_name => 'Note', 
           :conditions => ['important = ?', true]
end
```

You would then be able to do this

```
Person.find(:all, include: :important_notes)
```

Comment: Person.includes(...).where(...) returns only people associated with important notes. I need all the people, eager loading important notes.

Comment: The second solution solves the example, which I drew for the sake of clarity. However, reality is more complicated. Suppose now that I need important notes in a period (between start_date and end_date).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51870495/3090068 would return all the people, without introducing any new has_many relation, a bit ugly though...

Comment: The second solution is great since it returns all Person objects even if they don't have important notes. If you want notes in a period you can just use a normal where clause 
has_many :important_notes, -> { where('important = ? AND start_date > ? AND end_date < ?', true, 2.weeks.ago, 1.day.ago) }, class_name: "Note"

Answer (score 43):

Rails 5+ syntax:

```
Person.includes(:notes).where(notes: {important: true})
```

Nested:

```
Person.includes(notes: [:grades]).where(notes: {important: true, grades: {important: true})
```

Comment: This is not working as it was mentioned here: [Active Record Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). It is not returning Person objects which are not associated with a Note. It will only return Persons who have a note with master attribute equals to true

Answer (score 24):

Rails 4.2+:

**Option A - "preload": multiple selects, uses "id IN (...)"**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  has_many :important_notes, -> { where(important: true) }, class_name: "Note"
end

Person.preload(:important_notes)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT "people".* FROM "people"

SELECT "notes".* FROM "notes" WHERE "notes"."important" = ? AND "notes"."person_id" IN (1, 2)
```

**Option B - "eager_load": one huge select, uses "LEFT JOIN"**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  has_many :important_notes, -> { where(important: true) }, class_name: "Note"
end

Person.eager_load(:important_notes)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT "people"."id" AS t0_r0, "people"."name" AS t0_r1, "people"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "people"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "notes"."id" AS t1_r0, "notes"."person_id" AS t1_r1, "notes"."important" AS t1_r2 
FROM "people" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "notes" ON "notes"."person_id" = "people"."id" AND "notes"."important" = ?
```

Comment: See this answer if anyone wants to manually specify join parameter... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51870495/3090068

Answer (score 11):

Same was discussed in Japanese stackoverflow.  Quite hacky, but following seems to work, at least on rails 5.

```
Person.eager_load(:notes).joins("AND notes.important = 't'")
```

One important aspect is that by this way, you can write arbitrary join condition.  Down side is that you cannot use placeholder so you need to be careful when using params as the join condition.

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/22812/754

Comment: To use placeholders, you can use the ActiveRecord::Base#sanitize_sql_array method documented here : https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_array

`Person.eager_load(:notes).joins(Person.sanitize_sql_array(["AND notes.important = ?", true])`

Comment: This is great. Thank you! But there is also another limitation! If we want to eager_load multiple associations and there are multiple left joins, we can't control which join this will add an additional condition to... and I haven't been able to get over it lol

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to use the includes with a condition like Leo Correa's answer.
Insted I neeed to use:

```
Lead.includes(:contacts).where("contacts.primary" =>true).first
```

or you can also

```
Lead.includes(:contacts).where("contacts.primary" =>true).find(8877)
```

This last one will retrieve the Lead with id 8877 but will only include its primary contact

Answer (score 2):

For people interested, I tried this where a record attribute was false

```
Lead.includes(:contacts).where("contacts.primary" => false).first
```

and this doesn't work. Somehow for booleans only `true` works, so I turned it around to include `where.not`

```
Lead.includes(:contacts).where.not("contacts.primary" => true).first
```

This works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

A really simple example:

```rb
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { name: 'John' })
```

Notes:

- If your association is has_one, replace :posts with :post (watch the plural/singular).
- More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201167/5783745).

---

To take it one association further, if you had

```
thing.other_things.includes(:even_more_things).where(other_things: {col1: 'value'})
```

but you wanted to filter on `even_more_things`, you could use:

```
thing.other_things.joins(:even_more_things).where(even_more_things: { attribute: value })
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write the LEFT JOIN clause yourself by using joins:

```
Person.joins('LEFT JOIN "notes" ON "notes"."person_id" = "people.id" AND "notes"."important" IS "t"')
```

Not pretty, though.

Comment: But includes is used for easy load and joins works by lazy loading. So I think this in unappropriate

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
Person.includes(:notes).where(notes: { important: 't' })
```

make sure that the Note table name is notes and in person model the association like this :
has_many :notes
or you can change it
Person.includes(:asoociation).where(table_name: { important: 't' })