# How do I get this query result in a single query instead of N+1

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

A `pool_tournament` has many `pool_tournament_matches` and each match belongs to multiple `users`. A user has_many `pool_tournaments` and has_many `pool_tournament_matches`.

## pool_tournament.rb

```
has_many :pool_tournament_matches
```

## pool_tournament_match.rb

```
belongs_to :pool_tournament
has_many :pool_tournament_match_users, class_name: 'PoolTournamentMatchUser'
has_many :users, through: :pool_tournament_match_users
```

## user.rb

```
has_many :pool_tournament_users, class_name: 'PoolTournamentUser'
has_many :pool_tournaments, through: :pool_tournament_users

has_many :pool_tournament_match_users, class_name: 'PoolTournamentMatchUser'
has_many :pool_tournament_matches, through: :pool_tournament_match_users
```

There are 2 has_many through associations here. One is between the `user` and the `pool_tournament`. The other is between the `pool_tournament_match` and the `user`.

My query is to figure out which `pool_tournament_matches` only have 1 user. My query got me the list of matches but it's doing a N+1 query for each `pool_tournament_match`.

```
tournament.pool_tournament_matches.includes(:users).select { |m| m.users.count == 1 }
```

`PoolTournamentMatch Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "pool_tournament_matches".* FROM "pool_tournament_matches" WHERE "pool_tournament_matches"."pool_tournament_id" = $1  [["pool_tournament_id", 2]]`


  `PoolTournamentMatchUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "pool_tournament_match_users".* FROM "pool_tournament_match_users" WHERE "pool_tournament_match_users"."pool_tournament_match_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`


  `User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "pool_tournament_match_users" ON "users"."id" = "pool_tournament_match_users"."user_id" WHERE "pool_tournament_match_users"."pool_tournament_match_id" = $1  [["pool_tournament_match_id", 1]]`


   `(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "pool_tournament_match_users" ON "users"."id" = "pool_tournament_match_users"."user_id" WHERE "pool_tournament_match_users"."pool_tournament_match_id" = $1  [["pool_tournament_match_id", 2]]`


   `(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "pool_tournament_match_users" ON "users"."id" = "pool_tournament_match_users"."user_id" WHERE "pool_tournament_match_users"."pool_tournament_match_id" = $1  [["pool_tournament_match_id", 3]]`


   `(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "pool_tournament_match_users" ON "users"."id" = "pool_tournament_match_users"."user_id" WHERE "pool_tournament_match_users"."pool_tournament_match_id" = $1  [["pool_tournament_match_id", 4]]`

I also don't mind using RAW SQL and can post the schema if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: deleted my answer because it was incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348333/rails-includes-with-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have SQL do the counting for you. The following should work in Postgres (not sure about other databases):

```
tournament.pool_tournament_matches
  .select("pool_tournament_matches.*, COUNT(users.id) as user_count")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN pool_tournament_match_users ON (pool_tournament_match_users.pool_tournament_match_id = pool_tournament_matches.id)")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (pool_tournament_match_users.user_id = users.id)")
  .group("pool_tournament_matches.id")
  .select { |match| match.user_count > 0 }
```

Everything up to and incuding the `.group` produces a single query, and it attaches a 'user_count' attribute to the pool_tournament_matches it returns. So the final `.select`, which happens in memory, parses over the result without doing additional database calls.

Comment: You are a life saver! I will try to understand the query you posted and hope to get better at this!

Comment: I had a nearly identical problem in my own project a few months ago, so I just had to go dig it up and replace my table names with yours. Glad it was helpful.