# Ruby includes with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 6 app I've got model Journey with defined `active` scope:

```
class Journey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :journey_progresses
  has_many :journey_progresses, dependent: :destroy

  scope :active, -> { where(is_deleted: false) }
end
```

In my endpoint I want to show user journey_progress and for serializer journey itself. To do so I'm using below query which works well

```
      def query
        current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey)
      end
```

How to modify above query to show only active journeys? I tried to just add where to be like `current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey).where(is_deleted: false)` but I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column journey_progresses.is_deleted does not exist
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46153810/10443890) I tried with `current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey).where(journey: {is_deleted: false} )` but I'm getting another error:

```
Caused by PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "journey"
```

What is the right syntax for that sort of action?

Comment: I don't think so https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes

Answer (score 5):

You can merge a scope of a joined model.

```
current_user.journey_progresses.joins(:journey).merge(Journey.active)
```

This is better than testing for the `is_deleted` boolean because in future, if the definition of what makes a journey active changes, you won't need to modify the above line.

Comment: Ok but won't that slow down the query? include is a neat solution besides, I'm afraid about N+1 query...

Comment: It wont worked at all - I'm getting `[]` instead of list of journeys_progress

Comment: @mr_muscle Before worrying about any N+1 performance issues, you should make your query work in the first place

Comment: My query works well without `is_deleted`. With your merge I gets nothing - `[]`

Comment: Just checking... did you set a default of false when you created the column?  You might have `nil` instead of `false` in the database.  Try `scope :active, -> { where(is_deleted: [nil, false]) }` when you define the scope.

Comment: Also, it's not doing N+1 query, it merges in the conditions from the second association, it doesn't run the second association.

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing `includes` here. `includes` is only for optimization, to reduce number of queries going to the database.

Since you want to filter rows based on values in `journey`, you need to join it:

```
current_user.journey_progresses.joins(:journey)
```

As a general advice for these kind of problems I would recommend looking at the Rails log to see what SQL is generated at the end. Dealing with multiple `has_many`, `scope`, `include`, etc. can become confusing quickly.

**UPDATE**

You can actually combine `joins` with `includes` like this:

```
Foo.includes(:bars).where('bars.name = ?', 'example').references(:bars)
```

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes

Comment: This depends of the query. Sometimes active record WILL generate a join when you use `includes`. For example, in a CanCan app, the command `User.includes(:role).where(roles: {id:1}).to_sql` shows a LEFT JOIN in the console. I can't put the output query because of character limits.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve that? Includes is used for easy load and joins works by lazy loading. So I think this is inappropriate.

Comment: You mean *eager loading*?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following?

```
current_user
  .journey_progresses.
  .joins(:journey)
  .where("journeys.is_deleted = ?", false)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey).where(journey: {is_deleted: false} )
```

The above syntax is available from Rails 5.

You could try below possible ways,

1. Adding custom association

In **JourneyProgress Model**

```
class JourneyProgress < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :active_journey, -> { where(is_deleted: false) }, class_name: 'Journey'
end
```

and include the association while querying.

```
    current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:active_journey)
```

---

2. Adding default scope - But this scope will always be applied on querying from that model(https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class)

`default_scope -> { where(is_deleted: false) }`

Comment: I'm using Rails 6 and this query `current_user.journey_progresses.includes(:journey).where(journey: {is_deleted: false} )` won't worked. Failed with error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "journey"` like described earlier.

Comment: OK. Then you can try the methods that I have shared.

Comment: So based on shared code, will you use the deleted records and non deleted records in the app?

Comment: Yes, I will use both of them.

Comment: So the journey progresses will be marked as deleted when the journey gets deleted?

Comment: @mr_muscle The reason the query doesn't work is when passing nested where attribute you must specify the name of the table, not of the association. `.where(journey: {...})` should be `.where(journeys: {...})`, table names are plural by default.

Comment: @3limin4t0r you were right! it should be plural, now it works!